# Example to use 'System.Activities.Statements.StateMachine' class in C# or VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, state-machine, undo-redo

I feel in the need to ask for a full qualified example usage of the [System.Activities.Statements.StateMachine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.statemachine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class to store and restore the state of a `Control` instance (this means, I would like to store the state of a Control to replace the typical undo/redo methodology based on control properties and "commands").

I've been searching for home-made state-machine implementations on Google, I found a lot, but then I discovered this implementation of Microsoft in the .NET Framework Class Library (then now I have no reason to depend on any home-made implementation to reinvent the wheel), however, the MSDN has not a code sample to introduce on the usage of that class, and I didn't found any result on Google that demonstrates its usage (and the little pieces of code samples that I seen in the MSDN on some other related members I didn't understood it at all how do I should use them).

Then now I'm literally blind, trying to learn how to use that class and its related members by trial-and-error.

This below is what I tried by the moment, I'm stuck at the intent to "register" the state of the `obj` variable, concretelly at the [System.Activities.OutArgument.Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd486595(v=vs.110).aspx) and [System.Activities.OutArgument.Get](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465669(v=vs.110).aspx) methods that takes a [ActivityContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.activitycontext(v=vs.110).aspx) as first parameter and I don't know what value I should pass to them (in my code below a call to those methods throws an exception because the value cannot be *null*).

C# (translated by an online code translator, can have syntax errors):

```
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Statements;

// Create a container for statemachines
StateMachine sm = new StateMachine();

// Declare an object to test its state...
string obj = null;

// Modify the state of 'obj'.
obj = "hello";

// Save 1st state of 'obj'.
Activity<string> act1 = obj;
act1.Result = new OutArgument<string>();
act1.Result.Set(null, obj);
State state1 = new State();
state1.Entry = act1;

// Modify the state of 'obj'.
obj = "hello world";

// Save 2nd state of 'obj'.
Activity<string> act2 = obj;
act2.Result = new OutArgument<string>();
act2.Result.Set(null, obj);
State state2 = new State();
state2.Entry = act2;

// Add saved states into the statemachine collection.
sm.States.Add(state1);
sm.States.Add(state2);

// Modify the state of 'obj'.
obj = string.Empty;

// Restore last saved state of 'obj'.
obj = ((Activity<string>)sm.States.Last().Entry).Result.Get(null);
```

VB.NET:

```
Imports System.Activities
Imports System.Activities.Statements

' Create a container for statemachines
Dim sm As New StateMachine()

' Declare an object to test its state...
Dim obj As String

' Modify the state of 'obj'.
obj = "hello"

' Save 1st state of 'obj'.
Dim act1 As Activity(Of String) = obj
act1.Result = New OutArgument(Of String)
act1.Result.Set(Nothing, obj)
Dim state1 As New State()
state1.Entry = act1

' Modify the state of 'obj'.
obj = "hello world"

' Save 2nd state of 'obj'.
Dim act2 As Activity(Of String) = obj
act2.Result = New OutArgument(Of String)
act2.Result.Set(Nothing, obj)
Dim state2 As New State()
state2.Entry = act2

' Add saved states into the statemachine collection.
sm.States.Add(state1)
sm.States.Add(state2)

' Modify the state of 'obj'.
obj = String.Empty

' Restore last saved state of 'obj'.
obj = DirectCast(sm.States.Last().Entry, Activity(Of String)).Result.Get(Nothing)
```

...Also some instructions like `Activity<string> act1 = obj;` / `Dim act1 As Activity(Of String) = obj` I'm not sure if that is the right manner to do it.

PS: Note that in the code above I've used a String variable just to simplify things, but I require to save and restore the state of a `Control` as I explained before.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I suspect these classes were written for internal use by windows workflow foundation, and that's probably why there are no examples. Hope someone can help, though!

Comment: @RufusL you're not wrong, though it is not limited to internal use. There are examples of state machine workflows (see my answer) but they are mostly build using the WF designer, so no c# code there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `System.Activities` namespace belongs to the [Windows Workflow Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/overview). Activity classes in this namespace are used to build workflows, like [SharePoint workflows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-workflows-included-with-SharePoint-d74fcceb-3a64-40fb-9904-cc33ca49da56) for example.

The `StateMachine` class is a container for several child activities that together form a [State Machine Workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/state-machine-workflows).

Once you have defined a workflow you can run it using the Workflow Engine using a `WorkflowInvoker` or a `WorkflowApplication`. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/how-to-run-a-workflow):

> WorkflowInvoker provides a simple way for invoking a workflow as if it were a method call and can be used only for workflows that do not use persistence. WorkflowApplication provides a richer model for executing workflows that includes notification of life-cycle events, execution control, bookmark resumption, and persistence.

The `ActivityContext` you refer to holds information about the workflow runtime, e.g. the host that executes the activity. The runtime fills in the information so you cannot inject something yourself.

The reason that you won't find much examples of using the `StateMachine` class is that most workflows are build using a graphical designer that creates .XAML files and I don't think many are build using code only.

Now, given all of this you can see that for your scenario this is not a good fit and certainly not designed for undo/redo use cases.

There are framework/libraries that might be a better fit, like [this](http://doc.postsharp.net/undoredo-ui) from PostSharp.

Comment: I think don't understand at all the concept and meaning of "workflow", but you said those classes were not designed for this purpose (and then I should understand those classes ARE NOT capable to accomplish this kind of task in any tricky manner). Please correct me If i'm wrong. Thankyou for your asnwer. Just to advertise: The linked Undo/Redo functionality seems only available for WPF technology and WinRT, not WindowsForms (or at least it is not mentioned in the article).

Comment: The PostSharp undo/redo is done at model level (so you can apply undo/redo on the data that is bound to the control). See http://doc.postsharp.net/undoredo. And about the workflow itself, think of it as a framework that allows you to represent an ordered business process, such as the steps needed to approve a document, hire a candidate for a position, or make a purchase. These processes can execute in a short amount of time, but are typically long-running, in which the application will need to shut down to conserve memory between steps